# Change Worksheet CodeName in protected VBProject

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have a VBProject that's protected with `password(1)`. I am trying to add a worksheet and change its codename at run-time, but i get an `error 50289`

The code is called from `sheet1` through a click of a button.

```
Public Sub AddSheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets.Add
        Set sh = .ActiveSheet
        .VBProject.VBComponents(sh.CodeName).Name = "sh" & VBA.Minute(VBA.Now) & VBA.Second(VBA.Now)
        .Save
        Sheet1.Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

I really want to keep the project locked.
Is there a way to achieve this when the `VBProject` is locked?

Comment: There is a solution without using the password! You can create the Worksheet in a different Workbook that is not protected, edit CodeName by`Application.Run` running a macro that edits _CodeName, then copy to protected Workbook. Besides that you can use`Workbook.Names.Add`to create a Names assigned to the sheet, even it is renamed, if that is the reason for changeing CodeName. See [RenameProblems](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RenameProblems.aspx)

Comment: Hi PEH I know the project password and have set it to 123. I just want to be able to : > Unlock(with password at Run-time> "Do stuff..." >Lock again.

Answer (score 3):

**Not a Solution for the Question**
(I missed to turn view protection on ;( I only set a pwd. Shame on me!, but maybe someone benefits from the discovery of _CodeName or the hidden members.)

Although`Worksheet.CodeName`is read-only, there is a hidden property`Worksheet._CodeName`that can be edited! No need for climbing through unlocking project via API-Calls.

To view hidden members in Object-Browser, do right-click on it, then select`Show Hidden Member`.

```vb
`Public Sub AddSheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets.Add
        Set sh = .ActiveSheet
        sh.[_CodeName] = "sh" & VBA.Minute(VBA.Now) & VBA.Second(VBA.Now)
        .Save
        Sheet1.Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your input. But this doesn't work either I get the error '1004' - Method'_CodeName' of object'_Worksheet' Failed

Comment: @Joel Sorry, I missed the Lock Project for viewing checkbox ;[ Maybe there is an option to set CodeName on Worlsheets,Add

Answer (score 0):

As you can't edit CodeName while Project is protected and we don't want to unprotect by code, just use another Project, that is not protected.

This`temp.xlsm`Workbook contains a Function to edit the CodeName of a Worksheet and it returns a reference to that Sheet. This reference can be used to copy the Sheet to the protected Workbook.
The Function is executed by`Application.Run("temp.xlsm!EditCodeName", CodeName)`and returns the Sheet with edited CodeName.

Procedure to copy Worksheet:

```vb
Public Sub CopySheet()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim CodeName As String

    CodeName = "sh" & VBA.Minute(VBA.Now) & VBA.Second(VBA.Now)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsTemp = Application.Run("temp.xlsm!EditCodeName", CodeName)
    wsTemp.Copy After:=ws

End Sub
```

Function to edit CodeName in temp.xlsm (if you put that in a Module called`modCodeName`in the protected Workbook, the Procedure`CreateWB()`copies it to temp.xlsm on creation.

```vb
Public Function EditCodeName(ByVal CodeName As String) As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sh = .Worksheets(1)  
        sh.[_CodeName] = CodeName    
        Set EditCodeName = sh
    End With

End Function
```

And a Procedure to create the temp.xlsm Workbook

```vb
Sub CreateWB()

    Const CodeFile As String = "CodeFile.txt"
    Const TempWB As String = "temp.xlsm"

    With Workbooks.Add
        .SaveAs TempWB, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("modCodeName").Export CodeFile
        .VBProject.VBComponents.Import CodeFile
        .Close True
    End With

End Sub
```